# How to write a code in C that checks for repeated words in strings, and calculates their number of occurrences?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm right now writing a code for my coursework that analyzes a manually inserted text. I'm supposed to find the total number of non-space characters, and total words. Also, I'm supposed to find any repeated words in the string, then display them with the number of repetitions. I'm stuck in finding repeated words and displaying the number of repetitions. Also, my knowledge to C is limited, with the topics I know including pointers, strings, files, and functions, loops, if conditions, etc... Below is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num, numi, text, length, length1, word;
numi = 0;
word = 1;

int main()
{
    char text[] = "Dennis        MacAlistair Ritchie (September 9, 1941 - October 12, 2011) was an American computer scientist. He created the C programming language and, with long-time colleague Ken Thompson, the Unix operating system and B programming language. Dennis Ritchie was born in Bronxville, New York. His father was Alistair E. Ritchie, a long-time Bell Labs scientist and co-author of The Design of Switching Circuits on switching circuit theory. As a child, Dennis moved with his family to Summit, New Jersey, where he graduated from Summit High School. He graduated from Harvard University with degrees in physics and applied mathematics.";
    printf("Welcome to UNM Text Editor. Your original text is:\n\n");
    printf("%s", text);
    length = strlen(text);
    for (numi=0; numi<=length; numi++)
    {
        if (text[numi] == ' ')
        {
            length1++;
            if (text[numi + 1] != ' ')
            {
                word++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nThe total number of characters (without spaces) is: %d", length-length1);
    printf("\nThe total number of words is: %d", word);
}
```

Comment: Analyze the char stream, word by word according to your definition of a word, counting chars and words in the process. For each word, try to save it in a hash table with a count of one, unless it's already there, in which case increment the saved count for the word. The questions of how to manage the input, how to construct the hash table, and how to manage backend storage are kind of broad. In a language like C, you have a lot of options.

Comment: What you are trying to do is quite simple, so show what you have tried so far and we will be glad to help you showing what's wrong in your attempt.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Cubo78 I have successfully calculated the words and characters excluding spaces. Now, I'm stuck in finding and displaying repeated words along with the repetitions.

`char text[] = "this is a sample. this is not the original";
 printf("%s", text);`

In this example, I want to write a code to find the repeated words (this, is), displaying them, and displaying the number of times they were repeated (2 times in this case).

Comment: @Zelreedy update your question with the code.

Comment: @Cubo78 I have done so. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Rather than computing the length and using an index into the string, it is much more natural to do something like: `for (char *tp = text; *tp; tp++) { if (*tp == ' ') { if (tp[1] != ' ') word++; } else length++; }` . You might consider using `isspace` as well.

Comment: Or even simpler is to use while  -     const char* pch = text;  char ch;  while((ch = *pch++)){  if (ch == ' ') {   } }

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I'm more stuck in the part where I have to find repeated words and display their repetitions.

Comment: Before talking about the search of words, I can see at least two issues, both of them regarding illegal access beyond `text[]` array. 1) in for loop you should replace `numi<=length` with `numi<length`: you are currently accessing length+1 chars, that is the string terminator, and that's not probably what you was going to do. 2) in the loop you access `text[numi + 1]`. But what if `numi` points to the last element?

Comment: Talking about your word search task: has `strstr( )` function explicitly forbidden by your teacher? If not, google it and see if you can figure out a way to use it for searching words. Its use depends also on your constraints: do you have to look only for **full** words? Or for example you can also accept 'is' word inside longer words such as 'wish'?

Comment: @Cubo78 I have worked to modify both your comments. Moreover, our lecturer has not restricted us to anything. I haven't considered `strstr( )`, since we have only been briefly introduced to it. However, I will look it up thoroughly to see if I can apply it. Also, we're only supposed to find full words. Hopefully, I can figure it out, and if you don't mind, keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I've read in comments you already solved first two points so i'm going to focus mainly on repetitions.

To do it you can use Trie data structure, please take a look at below link.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-display-content/

it's in C++ but not so many things from C++ are really used so it can be easily rewrite to C. You need to add only a few lines to GeeksForGeeks code to make it work. Because it's your coursework perhaps you shouldn't just use whole code but write own one, but I would like to show you and general idea,

1. Add variable number of occurrences of "string" to struct:

   ```
   struct TrieNode
   {
       struct TrieNode* children[alpha_size];
       bool isLeaf;
       int occurrence; // <-- I ADDED IT HERE
   }
   ```
2. in the end of insert_node_function add:

   ```
   ...
   pCrawl->isLeaf = true;
   pCrawl->occurrence++; // <-- I ADDED IT HERE
   ...
   ```
3. Display only when number of occurrences bigger than 1

   void display(struct TrieNode* root, char str[], int level)
   {
       // If node is leaf node, it indicates end 
       // of string, so a null character is added 
       // and string is displayed 
       if (isLeafNode(root) && root->occurrence > 1)  // <-- I ADDED IT HERE
       {
           str[level] = '\0';
           cout << str << " " << root->occurrence << endl;  // <-- I ADDED IT HERE
       }
       ...

One thing that remains is how to read a single word from "text" (char text in your example). To make it easier you can remove all duplicated spaces and go through the text once again. Then you can copy word treating space as a delimiter (for instance by using strncat) and insert to trie.

To understand how trie works try to google it. There should be loads of info about it.